# Restoring Azure App Service backup to different site

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I use `Restore-AzureRmWebAppBackup` to restore an app service to a **different** existing site? This can usually be done in the portal, but for some reason the destination app service is not listed, even though it's in the same resource group.

Comment: Have you tried using the Restore-AzureRMWebAppBackup cmdlet? What error is it giving?

Comment: I didn't try it because there's no obvious option to specify a target app service. That's the whole point of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use Restore-AzureRmWebAppBackup to restore an app service to a different existing site?

Here is a sample code of restore web app from PowerShell.

```
$resourceGroupName = "target web app resource group name"
$appName = "target web app name"
$blobName = "backup blob name"
$storageAccountURL = "SAS URL of your blob container"
Restore-AzureRmWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appName -StorageAccountUrl $storageAccountURL  -BlobName $blobName -Overwrite
```

We can find the blob name from the restore page after you backup your web app.

[image]

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[Use PowerShell to back up and restore App Service apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-powershell-backup)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Unfortunately, their cmdlet doesn't return anything, and there's no obvious way to check status on a restore request. It took about 10 minutes, but it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the solution using Bash CLI:

prerequisite: A storage account with a container and the container URL for the same. The container URL contains the access the key (SAS). More information about the container URL can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

You can also use the following command to generate the SAS token:

```
az storage container generate-sas --name <container-name> --expiry <sas-expiry> --permissions <permissions> --account-name <account-name> --account-key <account-key>
```

To clone the app, use the following commands:

```
backupname=appname_`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`

az webapp config backup create --resource-group $OriginresourceGroupName --webapp-name $originAppName --backup-name $backupname --slot $OriginSlotName --container-url "$ContainerURL"

az webapp config backup restore --backup-name $backupname --container-url $ContainerURL --resource-group $TargetresourceGroupName --webapp-name $TargetAppname --overwrite --ignore-hostname-conflict
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below cmdlets to restore last successful backup to slot or app

```
    $resourceGroupName = "<<RG NAME>>"
    $primarywebappname = "<<APP NAME>>"
    $slotname = "<<SLOT NAME>>"

# Get the last Sucessfull BackupID of the backup you want to restore
    $backupID=Get-AzWebAppBackupList -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name `
    $primarywebappname|where BackupStatus -EQ "Succeeded" |select -Last 1 |select BackupId

# Get the backup object that you want to restore by specifying the BackupID
    $backup = (Get-AzWebAppBackupList -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name 
    $primarywebappname | where {$PSItem.BackupId -eq $backupID.BackupId}) 

# Restore the app by overwriting it with the backup data in the slot
    $backup |Restore-AzWebAppBackup -Slot $slotname -IgnoreConflictingHostNames -Overwrite

# Restore the app by overwriting into the exsisting App
    $backup |Restore-AzWebAppBackup -Overwrite
```